# javascript for loop inside a function then output it to the page

Tags: javascript

Here is my code. I am expecting "the number is 1, the number is 2..." to be out putted up to 5 but all that is outputted is the number is 0 not sure why.

```
<script>
var i=0;
function test(){

for(i=0;i<=5;i++){
    return "the number is" + i;
}
}
</script>
<script>
document.write(test());
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`return "the number is" + i;`
It (the 'point' of script execution) returns back from the function with the first loop at `i = 0`

Write it as http://jsfiddle.net/hNWrg/

```
function test(){
var out = '';
for(var i=0;i<=5;i++){
    out += "the number is" + i + "<br>";
}
return out;
}
```

Comment: @AndersKitson  `x += 2` is the same as `x = x + 2`

Answer (score 2):

your function is returning 0 the first time through the loop :-)  try this:

```
<script>
var i=0;
function test(){

for(i=0;i<=5;i++){
    document.write("the number is" + i);
}
}
</script>
<script>
test();
</script>
```